# Variable has not been assigned. when i instantiate the gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

The variable camera of joint has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the camera variable of the joint script in the inspector.

but i had already put the variable into the inspector

```
public Camera camera;

public GameObject bt;
```

Comment: Did you drag the desired GameObjects into 'camera' and 'bt' in the inspector? And are the GameObject's coordinates set so they can be instantiated?

Answer (score 0):

Did you drag all the references you put in the script in the inspector? If compiler says you have not assigned the variables then you have not done it :)